# MYSQL data select based on amount SUM

Tags: mysql

There is my table:

```
SELECT> SELECT * FROM table WHERE auctionID = 3 ORDER BY p DESC, bidTime ASC


id  auctionID   bidderID    amount  bidTime                     p
12  3           1           10000   2016-10-22 02:51:46.0000    70
10  3           2           10000   2016-10-21 03:56:00.0000    60
11  3           3           10000   2016-10-21 19:11:24.0000    35
5   3           4           10000   2016-10-18 21:59:36.0000    25
9   3           5           10000   2016-10-20 23:54:26.0000    25
```

Now i need output of winning bids, based on SUM(amount) and still use ORDER BY p DESC, bidTime ASC.

TOTAL_AMOUNT = 30000;

In this case it should select ID 12,10,11 id 5,9 is more than auction limit 30000.

Comment: dont understand how is related the `SUM(amount)` with `Total_Amount`

Comment: You have to give more details on your question. I don't see how `SUM(amount)` could be any different than `amount` at first. Is `amount` always 10000? Is `TOTAL_AMOUNT` always 30000? Does it have to be a `SELECT` or could it be a `function`? etc.

Comment: TOTAL_AMOUNT is variable which i will provide to query to every auction